# Excel show date where the value in the next column is x

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I will try to explain my problem using a screenshot:

[image]

What would be the needed formula in G3 if I want it to contain all the cells (or, if that is too complicated, only the cell) where the value is equal to F3?

It seems rather easy at first sight, but even after searching and asking around for a bit I couldn't find an answer.

Edit:

I went with @ThrowingSpoon's answer, but @A.S.H's would have worked too

Edit 2: After a bit of playing around I instead went with @A.S.H's answer, as it does not return an error if there are duplicates.

Comment: Did you try using `VLOOKUP()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try using `=LOOKUP()`

See this example:

`=LOOKUP(C2,A2:A9,B2:B9)` [Using this function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb)

[image: Using the lookup function]

---

Data i used:

```
numbers  related number number to search    related number
24       412            21                  999
145      541        
52       5      
8        213        
62       52     
21       999        
54       423        
74       41
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew there would be a short solution.

For the other germans out there, the german command is VERWEIS.

Comment: Already planned on doing that, it was only too early to accept an answer :D

Comment: how would you do this if 21 would appear multiple times, to list all related numbers? I understand that that might be a lot harder

Answer (score 3):

It's a classical `Index/Match`. Unfortunately `VLookup` is not adequate here because it wants the search column to be the leftmost in the target range.

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(F3,B:B,0))
```